# Linux memory mapping a file with HUGETBL

Tags: linux, mmap, memory-mapped-files, huge-pages

I'm interested in using a memory mapped file for fast I/O, ive done this a few times before without issue.
I think I'm also hitting a page boundary overhead anytime I access memory past 4k ( I'm streaming data into this memory map ).
So I was thinking I can use huge pages to get to 2MB page sizes for efficiency here and avoid the small page size overhead and penalties.
When I try to allocate my memory mapped file with HUGETLB though, mmap fails with an invalid argument error.
So my basic question is, are hugetable pages supported with memory mapped files?

mmap call for reference, memsize is a multiple of 2M. mmapfd is a file descriptor to the file.
Note that this call works fine if i dont set MAP_HUGETLB

`m_mmap = mmap( nullptr, memsize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED| MAP_HUGETLB, mmapfd, 0 )`

Comment: And what is `nullptr' ?

Comment: @wildplasser https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr

Answer (score 1):

I believe MAP_HUGETLB have to be used with MAP_ANONYMOUS.

From the patch notes that added the MAP_HUGETLB flag (https://lwn.net/Articles/353828/):

*"This patch set adds a flag to mmap that allows the user to request
a mapping to be backed with huge pages.  This mapping will borrow
functionality from the huge page shm code to create a file on the
kernel internal mount and use it to approximate an anonymous mapping.
The MAP_HUGETLB flag is a modifier to MAP_ANONYMOUS and will not work
without both flags being preset."*

All the documentation I have seen also only specifies use-examples with anonymous mappings.